# How to make a thread wait on std::list for a value?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a typical scenario:
Let's say thread A and thread B are going to access std:list.
Thread A is going to push an item to list and thread B is going to pop the item from the list.

My question is: How to make thread B wait until there is a data inside the queue.

Comment: What do you mean with regards to restricting the list items to a specific value? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `std::list` you probably want to use a container with thread safety built in such as [`boost::lockfree::queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) or [TBB `concurrent_queue`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm).

Answer (score 2):

> How to make thread B wait until there is a data inside the queue.

Check out [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). With a condition variable, a thread can wait (spin and then sleep) on the variable until a different thread signals on the same variable and wakes up the waiting thread.

Comment: I'd like to remind people to pay special attention to the Predicate lambda in the example in the link. The `wait()` call will continue to wait until the Predicate function returns true. This is very important.

Comment: In case if I use POSIX condition_variable do I need to have two pthread_mutex ? One mutex which I need for making pthread_cond_wait and other to have the read/write lock on the queue?

Comment: @Bhush You'd generally use only one `std::mutex`. Take a look at an example http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/